# ReadTheDocs robots.txt and sitemap.xml

Tags: robots.txt, read-the-docs, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

ReadTheDocs auto-generates a `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` for projects. Each time I deploy a new minor version of my project (ex. `4.1.10`), I hide previous minor versions (ex. `4.1.9`). ReadTheDocs adds entries for all versions to `sitemap.xml`, but hidden versions are also added to `robots.txt`. The result is that submitted sitemaps to Google Search Console, at this point, result in "Submitted URL blocked by robots.txt" errors, since the previous sitemap entry is now blocked by the newly generated `robots.txt`.

ReadTheDocs generates a sitemap URL for each version, so we have an entry like this for `4.1.9`, for example:

```xml
<url>
   <loc>https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/4.1.9/</loc>
   <lastmod>2020-08-12T18:57:47.140663+00:00</lastmod>
   <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
   <priority>0.7</priority>
</url>
```

And when `4.1.10` is release and the previous minor version is hidden, the newly generated `robots.txt` gets:

```
Disallow: /en/4.1.9/ # Hidden version
```

I believe this `Disallow` is what then causes the Google crawler to throw the error.

Realistically, all I want in the `sitemap.xml` are `latest`, `develop`, and `stable`, I don't much care to have every version crawled. But all I'm able to configure, [as I understand it from ReadTheDocs docs](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hosting.html#custom-robots-txt-pages), is a static `robots.txt`.

What I want is to publish a static `sitemap.xml` of my own instead of using the auto-generated one. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with a few ideas, here is the solution I came other with. Since this question is asked frequently and often opened as a bug against ReadTheDocs on GitHub (which it's not, it just appears to be poorly supported and/or documented), I'll share my workaround here for others to find.

As mentioned above and in the docs, while ReadTheDocs allows you to override the auto-generated `robots.txt` and publish your own, you can't with `sitemap.xml`. Unclear why. Regardless, you can simply publish a *different* `sitemap.xml`, I named mine `sitemap-index.xml`, then, tell your `robots.txt` to point to your custom sitemap.

For my custom `sitemap-index.xml`, I only put the pages I care about rather then ever generated version (since `stable` and `latest` are really what I want search engines to be crawling, not versioned pages):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <url>
        <loc>https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/stable/</loc>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/</loc>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>0.9</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/develop/</loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.1</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I created my own `robots.txt` that tells Google not to crawl anything except my main branches *and* points to my custom `sitemap-index.xml`.

```
User-agent: *

Disallow: /

Allow: /en/stable

Allow: /en/latest

Allow: /en/develop

Sitemap: https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sitemap-index.xml
```

I put these two files under `/docs/_html`, and to my Sphinx `conf.py` file (which is in `/docs`) I added:

```py
html_extra_path = ["_html"]
```

Here is this shown in the repo too, [for reference](https://github.com/alexdlaird/pyngrok/blob/6f38339f4db271f1a94acf81d8e9665f915d7252/docs/conf.py#L105).

After ReadTheDocs rebuilds the necessary branches, give `/en/latest/sitemap-index.xml` to [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console) instead of the default one, ask Google to reprocess your `robots.txt`, and not only will the crawl errors be resolved, Google will properly index a site that hides previous minor versions.